# Execute command line via php?

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf, shellexecute

How I can execute those two command line via php:

wkhtmltopdf www.google.com gg.pdf

&

oofice -headless -nologo -pt cup-pdf my.doc

they both return a pdf file and download into my home directory.

I want to know the way to execute those command from my html page via php.

Thanks.

Comment: See [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566248/cant-execute-php-script-using-php-exec)

Answer (score 15):

You should take a look at the [**System program execution**](http://www.php.net/exec) section of the manual : PHP provides several functions that can be used to launch external commands / programs, including :

- [**`exec()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) -- which can store the output of the command in an array
- [**`shell_exec()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) -- which returns, as a string, the output of the command
- [**`system()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) -- which echoes the output of the command

Comment: Thanks Pascal for your answer,

Comment: Thanks for your answer,

However, I tryed the command 
echo shell_exec('wkhtmltopdf --version -');
and it dose outputs the version info. but whene I run 
echo shell_exec('wkhtmltopdf www.google.com my.pdf');
It dose nothing,
 wkhtmltopdf is a package that take the url: www.google.com converted to pdf and save my.pdf to the same diractory.

How can I handle a command line that result a pdf via php?

Answer (score 2):

To create a pdf from php(in linux) you must use a wrapper.

```
$cmd = '/usr/bin/xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0, 1920x1080x24" /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf http://google.com /tmp/google.pdf';

exec($cmd);
```