# Create DB/User/Privileges using PHP but for a domain on Plesk

Tags: php, mysql, database, plesk

I'm trying to auto create a database/user and grant privelges for a specific domain that was created within Plesk.

The trouble I'm having is I want the database to still be available if you access that user via Plesk control panel.

Here's what I have:

```
$con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","pass");
mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE ".$db."",$con)or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("GRANT ALL ON ".$db.".* to  ".$user." identified by '".$dbpass."'",$con) or die(mysql_error());
```

This will work, but it won't show up in Plesk for the domain I'd like it to.  How do I tie this database to a specific domain within plesk?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I see this question is super old, but I was wondering the same thing, and found a command line tool built into Plesk 10.x that allows you to do exactly what you need.

**Create database**

```
/usr/local/psa/bin/database --create new_database_name -domain the_domain_in_question.com -print-id -server localhost -type mysql
```

**To create a new user for a database:**

```
/usr/local/psa/bin/database --update new_database_name -add_user new_username -passwd new_password
```

The examples create a new MySQL database called "new_database_name" for the domain "the_domain_in_question.com" and then adds a new user called "new_username" with the password “new_password”

You just need get PHP to execute that. [Here's an article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796617/execute-command-line-via-php) with some info about that. I'll be testing this out next.