# Txt file Compression in rar format with php script

Tags: php, file, compression, rar

I am creating .rar file using exec() in PHP function.

Below is script

```
exec('C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe a carchivo.rar Details.txt');
```

this script is running without any error but not creating rar file.

Please help me to sort out this. Is there any other method for cerating .rar compressed files ?

Thanks in Advence

Comment: You need to debug your `exec()` call so you see its errors - there are many existing resources for that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't execute PHP script using PHP exec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566248/cant-execute-php-script-using-php-exec)

Comment: I haven't used winrar in forever but I seem to remember you don't add the .rar part to the filename, try: `exec('C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe a carchivo Details.txt');`

Comment: Dale : Thanks... Tried but not working

Answer (score 0):

There may be errors, but you are not checking for them.  Try the following :

```
$errors = array();
exec('C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe a carchivo.rar Details.txt', $errors);

var_dump($errors);
```

This should provide you with a simple response of what the result of the `exec()` is.

Without further information it is difficult to identify the possible cause of your current issue.

Comment: KamiL:Thanks... But its returning null array

Comment: I suspect, that the \ is considered a single escape and it should be \\ but without error output it is difficult to confirm. Can you try? Also confirm that the permissions are set for whatever user is running the website.