# Execute a script in PHP from another PHP file (exec)

Tags: cron, exec, daemon, php

Originally I had a cronjob that executed a php file every day. Apparently the php file was to heavy and the cronjob was not executing it.

I opted for creating a Daemon that sleeps for 24hrs and works perfectly well, except that I believe that the server kills this process after a certain time due to its inactivity. I have a DEAMON that runs every 5 minutes and this one never stops, but the one that waits for 24 hrs always stops working.

My plan is to create a cronjob that checks if the process is running, if not to execute it:

```
exec("ps auxwww|grep _DAEMON.php|grep -v grep", $output);
if(empty($output)){
   exec("php -f _DAEMON.php");
}
```

For some reason this is not working, `exec("ps auxwww|grep _DAEMON.php|grep -v grep", $output)` does detect perfectly well if the script is running or not, so `exec("php -f _DAEMON.php")` is the one that doesn't work.

I tried to `print_r` $status from `exec("php -f _DAEMON.php",$status);` and this is what I got:

```
Array
(
    [0] => X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
    [1] => Content-type: text/html
    [2] => 
)
```

I tried `exec("php-cli -f _DAEMON.php")` and worked perfectly well, but since the file I am calling is a daemon, `php-cli` makes it part of my original file (some kind of `include()` I believe) and freezes my original file, it does create a separate new process for the daemon, but the original file loads forever.

Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: `_DAEMON.php` is different from `_RANDOMSD.php`. So what is the result of executing `exec("php -f _DAEMON.php");` ?

Comment: so sorry typo. I just fixed it

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566248/cant-execute-php-script-using-php-exec

Comment: Thanks @ShivanRaptor this worked, now the problem is that whatever is executed in php-cli becomes part of the original script, and since my second script is a daemon it freezes. :(

Comment: @ShivanRaptor please look at the bottom of my question, I added your solution and the problem I got into, thanks!

Comment: the exec function will probably freeze the current script until _DAEMON.php is finished. Have you `error_reporting(E_ALL);` somewhere to get more errors feedbacks ?

Comment: Yes @WiMantis, no errors, as you say it simply freezes the current script until _DAEMON.php is finished, problem is it will never finish.

Comment: @WiMantis, I decided to create a new question with my new problem as this one might get too long. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500071/detect-when-a-script-delays-and-allow-it-to-skip-or-continue-in-php Thanks!

Comment: I'll keep commenting here for now since I think things are getting more complicated than they should be lol :P A server killing process due to inactivity, is that really possible with a daemon ? maybe the daemon crashes at some point ? you could also try to cut the long 24h sleep in little naps ^^ lets say you divide it by 24, you do a sleep of 1 hour and increment a counter each time the script pass in the daemon loop, when it reaches 24, execute the daemon code