# Detect when a script delays and allow it to skip or continue in PHP

Tags: php, delay, daemon, freeze

I have a file, lets say file1.php, that within the script executes a file using: `exec("php-cli -f _DAEMON.php")` after executing the `exec()` command, it needs to run more code, the problem is that `_DAEMON.php` as its name says, is a Daemon and it will never stop running, so it freezes file1.php without allowing the rest of the code to run.

Is there a way to allow the code to continue executing even if `exec("php-cli -f _DAEMON.php")` has not finished. Or to detect if the code delays for more than x seconds/milliseconds, to continue?

Thanks.

Comment: why not using ajax? You can do a request on file1.php asking to run your exec() on an other page. Or using hidden iframe...

Comment: It is not executed on the front end.

Comment: Ajax is Asynchronous JavaScript. It mean it can call any php page, execute anything asynchronized. For example, you can start to load your exec() when file1.php finished to load.

Comment: @Dorian_gd, JavaScript is a client-side scripting language, not server side, I can not use AJAX within PHP. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript

Comment: you said file1.php, how you can say you cannot use ajax whitin php?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using a socket (curl might work with a low timeout, not sure if it'll kill the script though offhand).  Not ideal, will add some overhead.

http://phplens.com/phpeverywhere/?q=node/view/254

Also, doriana_gd was probably referring to something like node.js, server side javascript